# What is a good name for a configuration value that holds that name of a table or view?

Tags: database-design, naming-conventions

Is there a database term for "table or view"?
In my app, the table name I'm pulling data from is configurable using the configuration setting `UserTableName`
Now the DBA went and renamed the table but created a view using the original name.
So nothing changed on my side but now I feel that `UserTableName` is misleading and I would like to change it to User*Whatever*Name where *Whatever* is a term for a table or view.
Is there such a thing or am I just being an idiot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical models use the terms entity/attribute; physical models use table/column.  I don't know if a modeler would object, but maybe you can call it "UserEntity".

Here's a question: Why should it matter?  When you write a query in SQL, you don't know or care that it's a table or view. Why should your schema?

Comment: You're right, I don't care -- that's why I realized that naming the configuration field "UserTableName" is not abstract enough. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The term "relation" applies to a table or a view.  In fact, relation also applies to the result of a query.

Comment: If it's done right - no duplicates permitted in the result set. :D

Answer (score 1):

How about "Database Object" or "DBObject"?

Answer (score 0):

what about "`UserDataSource`" ?

Comment: thanks, but that won't work - UserDataSource is already a name of my class.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with what you have got.  That's what the folk at Oracle did for their data dictionary (view names appear in a column called table_name sometimes).